# Rearranjar informações de cada linha em outro formato

Tags: regex, sublime-text

Estou usando o Sublime, e tenho este padrão:

```
1   "1124293"   70,12   77,12   03/07/2018 00:00:00 2056
1   "1002953"   53,44   60,44   29/05/2018 00:00:00 2279
1   "55910" 0   563,07  06/12/2011 00:00:00 6653
1   "44225" 1013503,86  2729528,32  30/03/2009 00:00:00 14056
1   "1243284"   6260,4  16925,9 19/02/2019 00:00:00 27626
```

Preciso que seja transformado no padrão abaixo: o primeiro campo **sempre** será 1, preciso da informação que está entre aspas (ids) e da data, que será alterada para o formato yyy-mm-aa e entre aspas, e adicionado vírgulas como separador:

```
1,"1124293","2018-07-03"
1,"1002953","2018-05-29"
1,"55910","2011-05-06"
1,"44225","2009-03-30"
1,"1243284","2019-02-19"
```

É possível fazer isso utilizando regex?

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é usar esta regex:

```
^1\s+("\d+").*(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}) \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*$
```

E substituir por esta:

```
1,$1,"$4-$3-$2"
```

Eu uso os [marcadores](https://regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` que indicam o início e fim de cada linha.

Depois eu coloco o 1 fixo, já que ele não muda, e em seguida `\s+` para pegar um ou mais espaços. Depois eu coloco os números entre aspas: `\d+` é um ou mais dígitos, e as aspas são elas mesmas (o caractere `"`). Só que tudo isso está entre parênteses, pois isto forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que eu posso pegar depois (como é o primeiro par de parênteses, então é o grupo 1, que eu posso referenciar depois com `$1`).

Em seguida, o "miolo" não me interessa então eu usei `.*` mesmo (zero ou mais caracteres, basicamente qualquer coisa). Em seguida eu pego os dígitos da data, cada parte entre parênteses para formar um grupo de captura próprio: um para o dia, outro para o mês e outro para o ano. Também coloco os `\d` para o horário (que talvez nem seja necessário, é apenas para validar que vou pegar a data, desde que tenho o horário logo depois), e por fim `.*` para pegar qualquer coisa que tenha depois, até o final da linha.

Ao substituir, basta colocar os grupos de captura nos lugares que você quer. No caso, o grupo 1 (referenciado por `$1`) é o número que está entre aspas. O segundo grupo (`$2`) é o dia, o terceiro (`$3`) é o mês e o quarto (`$4`) é o ano. Então basta rearranjar as informações da forma que você quer.

---

Claro, se quiser ser mais específico e validar exatamente o formato de cada linha, poderia ser algo como:

```
^1\s+("\d+")\s+\d+(?:,\d{1,2})*\s+\d+(?:,\d{1,2})*\s+(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}) \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\d+$
```

Para os números do "miolo" que não me interessa, usei `\d+(?:,\d{1,2})*` (um ou mais dígitos, seguido *opcionalmente* por vírgula e um ou dois dígitos - assim ele também pega o zero, por exemplo). Desta forma ele valida exatamente o formato da linha, enquanto pega os dados que você quer nos grupos de captura.

Mas se você já garante que todas as linhas estão no formato correto, a primeira regex já é suficiente.

Comment: Funcionou perfeito, hkotsubo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @RodrigoSantos Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.